# How to allow a single serviceaccount in kubernetes to use roles from different clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, service-accounts

I have a question regarding ServiceAccount. In a single ServiceAccount, it needs to use each role from different clusters. However, using the Annotation, the ServiceAccount can’t use role from different clusters and the roles can’t be combined either.
(eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: “arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/role1”, eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: “arn:aws:iam::0987654321:role/role2")
Is there a solution to implement this idea?